# How do you print to the REPL from the CPython source?

Tags: python, c, development-environment, visual-studio-debugging, cpython

I am trying to get some printf info from compile.c to the REPL.   Specifically, just to get a "hello world" of sorts, I modified compiler_for as follows:

```
compiler_for(struct compiler *c, stmt_ty s)
{
    basicblock *start, *body, *cleanup, *end;

    printf("entering compiler_for \n");

    start = compiler_new_block(c);
    body = compiler_new_block(c);
```

I built it using:

```
 PCbuild/build.bat -E -d -p x64
```

And ran it on Cygwin as:

```
   ./go
```

Here is the detail on the go script and output:

```
Vostro@DESKTOP-UGP94US /c/Users/Vostro/Downloads/Python-3.10.2/PCbuild/amd64
$ go
hi

Vostro@DESKTOP-UGP94US /c/Users/Vostro/Downloads/Python-3.10.2/PCbuild/amd64
$ cat go
./python.exe target.py

Vostro@DESKTOP-UGP94US /c/Users/Vostro/Downloads/Python-3.10.2/PCbuild/amd64
$ cat target.py
for i in range(1):
    print("hi")
```

in the amd64 library.

It is not at all surprising that this did not produce an output.   I guess I could try to get it to work in the Visual Studio IDE.   For whatever reason, I have had no luck building in the IDE (using the .sln), and have not yet tried opening the sln after building with the build.bat to see if the output is in the console output window.  Even if it is, however, I'm guessing it would be much handier to see the result in the REPL.

Does anyone know how this is typically done (for example) by the Python contributors when they are debugging or others that make mods to the source?

Thanks!

Comment: `compiler_for` is used to compile a for-loop and isn't just run by default.

Comment: yes, I should have included that when I run python.exe, I subsequently run the following from the REPL:

for i in range(1):
      print("hi")

Comment: I've now modified the question to include more detail.

Comment: (Also, based on some earlier errors I've seen during the build, it appears to me that the build process itself calls the built compiler_for to complete the build.)

Comment: Thinking about it a bit more deeply, I'm guessing I might have to add the bytecode to do it?   If so, uggghh..   :-)

Comment: I just now noticed that the output from printf does, in fact, get printed during the build process, but not while running the python executable.    i'm guessing, based on this, it has to do with some sort of redirect or bitbucket associated with the runtime?

Comment: For example, in the freeze portion of the build:
 _socket.vcxproj -> C:\Users\Vostro\Downloads\Python-3.10.2\PCbuild\amd64\_socket_d.pyd
  _freeze_importlib.vcxproj -> C:\Users\Vostro\Downloads\Python-3.10.2\PCbuild\amd64\_freeze_importlib_d.exe
  compiler_for ---> hi there!
  compiler_for ---> hi there!
  compiler_for ---> hi there!
  compiler_for ---> hi there!
  compiler_for ---> hi there!
  enering compiler_for
  leaving compiler_for

  enering compiler_for
  leaving compiler_for

Comment: I got Visual Studio to work from the .sln file (after first building from the command line), and the output of VS works as expected while running Debug->Start Debugging and then adding the for loop to the REPL in the debug session.  From the REPL in the debug session, I do see the output of my printf statements.    Now the question is:  "Why doesn't this work from the Cygwin command line?"

Comment: I personally don't know the answer, but I would suggest editing your most recent comments into the question itself.

Comment: That is a good suggestion.   I will try to do that.   I also have a partial answer to the question and am trying to decide whether to delete the question or leave it for someone else who might have a similar question at some point.    The solution was so simple, it seems almost silly to leave the question.  One the other hand, I feel like if I had found this Q&A in my searches, the discourse would have saved me significant time.   Oh, and the problem?  I was using python.exe instead of python_d.exe, lol.   Executable dyslexia if you will! :-)